# I got ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer while trying to scrape

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Anyone can help me? I got these error while I am trying to scrape using BeautifulSoup,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

myUrl = "https://www.tokopedia.com/discovery/produk-terlaris?source=homepage.top_carousel.0.38454"
#open the connection
uClient = uReq(myUrl)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

product = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "css-6bc98m e1uv83qc1"})
print(len(product))
```

and this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ....
 ....
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 911, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need `User-Agent` headers, otherwise the server (correctly) thinks you're a bot.

The second thing is you won't get anything from that website, as almost the entire contents is behind `JS` (JavaScript), which basically means `BeautifulSoup` won't see it.

I've fixed your code, so there's no more error, but, as I've said, there aren't any divs you're after in the `HTML` you get back.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = "https://www.tokopedia.com/discovery/produk-terlaris?source=homepage.top_carousel.0.38454"
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36",
}
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(my_url, headers=headers).text, "html.parser")

product = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "css-6bc98m e1uv83qc1"})
print(len(product))
```

This prints `0`.

What you could do is explore `selenium` or inspect the traffic and see if there's an API endpoint exposed.